# Tensorflow image too small to display results properly

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

Is there a possible way for me to resize or change the way the results are being displayed for my object detection?

[image: This is my current result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think from your question you are asking how to upsample an image. There are a few ways, the simplest in my opinion is to use Pillow see here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("hopper.jpg")

# Provide the target width and height of the image
(width, height) = (im.width * 2, im.height * 2)
im_resized = im.resize((width, height))
```